# Shortcut for finding file on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio

What is the Visual Studio-like shortcut of control+comma for finding files in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will find a Resource (.xml, .properties, .java, .class, .anything), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will find a Type (.java)